# Cannot Create Centerline between 2 Holes in Solidworks Drawing

Tags: solidworks, drafting

[image]

I am new to Solidworks, my part has several holes (created using the Hole Wizard) which needs Centerlines drawn to connect them.

However when I click on the Centerline tool in the Drawing, then click on one hole followed by another hole, I get the error message

```
Unable to create centerline from the selected entities
```

What should be the correct way to create the centerlines?

Comment: [I'm not in front of SolidWorks, so I can't reproduce your issue.]  I remember seeing this message myself too.  Select centers of the holes, rather than the edge of the hole.

Comment: @NickAlexeev My memory is pretty shaky on Solidworks; but that sounds like the kind of thing that would work.  It could be trying to find a "centreline" between two circles, which doesn't really make sense, because circles are not points.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I cant seem to select the center of the hole because theres nothing in the center...

Comment: create the centre points first - join with the line then add the holes after... just guessing though as I don't have / use solidworks but used other packages...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the suggestion, in Solidworks I am not able to select the center points with the tool used for creating centerlines.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sketch a line using the line tool (under the Sketch tab) [image], and then simply select "For Construction"

Under the sketch tab, you should also be able to access the Centerline tool that will skip this step for you.  Click the drop-down menu on the Line tool, and select Centerline [image: Centerline Sketch Tool] .  Alternatively, select Tools > Sketch Entitities > Centerline

[image: Centerline]

The "centerline" tool you tried using (under the Annotation tab) essentially will draw a line midway between two other lines.  Notice that the icon for the tool appears to be a side profile of a shaft.  [image: Centerline Icon]

Answer (score 0):

Go in sketch, [image], select centerline, draw between holes.
[image]